# Pass parameters to log4j.properties in hadoop jar call

Tags: java, hadoop, logging, mapreduce, log4j

I have a **`log4j.properties`** file which contains the following line:

```
log4j.appender.fileOut.File=${log.dir}/${stage}_${date}.log
```

If I use only java (not Hadoop MapReduce), the following works:

```
java -cp <jar_dependencies> -Dstage=matching -Ddate=2018-11-26 -Dlog.dir=/tmp/project_folder/log/ -Dlog4j.configuration=file:path/to/conf/log4j.properties main_class
```

I.e. the **log4j parameters** are correctly passed and replaced. However, when trying to run a mapReduce job making a **`hadoop jar`** command-line call:

```
hadoop jar <input_jar_here.jar> -Dstage=matching -Ddate=2018-11-26 -Dlog.dir=/tmp/project_folder/log/ -Dlog4j.configuration=file:path/to/conf/log4j.properties -libjars <jar_dependencies>
```

it doesn't work i.e. the parameters are not passed/replaced.

**NOTE:** If I hardcode the parameter values in the log4j.properties, the previous **hadoop jar** call works.

How to pass parameters so that they're correspondingly filled/set in the `log4j.properties` file considering a **`hadoop jar`** call?

Please let me know if I can be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

From [hadoop doc](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html)

> -D property=value     Use value for given property.

Looks like there should be space after -D instead of java syntax

> -Dproperty=value

Comment: No. If I add spaces when passing params it doesn't work (from experience with other parameters that I'm passing)